# Get hash value from URL using Classic asp

Tags: jquery, asp-classic

I am trying to find a way to retrieve the value of a hash in asp like mysite.com#main  I have tried all of the server variables but not seem to pick up the #main.  I know how to get it via javascript, but need to somehow get that variable into a classic asp variable. Sure appreciate any help.  i have been looking for hours.  Best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not possible.

The browser doesn't include the hash and what's after it in the URL, it only sends what's before the hash sign to the server.

Comment: Thanks Guffa.  At least I can quit searching and start looking for another way to make this all work.  Best.